# proxying requests from a secure application

Tags: node.js

im trying to proxy requests from a secure web application(https) in node (its an internal application) and im not quite sure how to do it...
the below is my code which works when i try it from an non secured app (http).

It just strips out a page name and uses it in another app. I read the docs but still not sure how to do it. Do i need to have the ssl info from my application for this to work?

```
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var request = require('request');
var app = require('express.io')();
app.http().io();

// 
// Create proxy server 
// 
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://localhost:9000'}).listen(9085);

// Send the client html.
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client1.html');
})

proxy.on('error', function (err, req, res) {
  res.writeHead(500, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
  res.end('Something went wrong!');
});

app.all('/Domain/*', function(req, res) {

  console.log(req.url);

   if (req.url.indexOf("Page.do") > -1) {

    // URL to Atlas
    var otherAppURL = "http://myotherapp/pages/";

    var temp = req.url.split("Page.do")[0].split("/");
    var pageName = temp[temp.length - 1];;

    app.io.broadcast('update', {
       url: atlasURL + pageName + '.html'
    }); 

   };


  // This doesnt work
  //var url = "https://mysecureapp:9044" + req.url;

  // This works
  var url = "http://localhost:9080" + req.url;   
  req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);

})

app.listen(9000);
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you're trying to do, please elaborate on `im trying to proxy requests from a secure web application(https) in node (its an internal application)` and describe your usecase. Also, in your code, `This doesnt work` is not very helpful, what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need an SSL Certificate for an HTTPS connection. According to the website https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-is-an-ssl-certificate/ :

> The standard HTTP is changed to HTTPS, automatically telling the browser that the connection between the server and the browser must be secured using SSL.

This means that with an HTTPS connection, you need to have the server secured with SSL.
For connecting with HTTPS in Node, this website might help you:
http://gaboesquivel.com/blog/2014/nodejs-https-and-ssl-certificate-for-development/

Comment: thanks for this.... so in order for it to work i need to get the certificates of my secured application and somehow reuse them in my program...

Answer (score 0):

Ok i might be mistaking but this line doesn't make sense ,

`req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);`

by the time the route handler hits, the *req* object is ready
so `req.pipe` has no meaning. 
please check that *url* returns a valid response

`request(url).pipe(res);` should work

http / https is not an issue

Comment: that line i googled. im not sure how it works but what i was trying to do was to send a response back to the application im proxying the requests from so that it behaved as normal.
It does work but only with http. If the application is secured it doesnt.
I just tried it with your suggestion and got

Comment: stream.js:94
          throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
    Error: self signed certificate in certificate chai
        at Error (native)
        at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:927:36)
         at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:458:8)